# Calling a POSTMAN Mock Server from IIB

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, postman-mocks

I have been trying to call a mock server I made on POSTMAN from IIB flow that I deployed on local. But I am getting java.net.UnknownHostException: 77735a12-4076-4e16-af64-79f0f9b70b61.mock.pstmn.io I have tested the mock server after creating it, it works fine. But this time I am trying to hit it from outside POASTMAN. Do I have to include CORS headers here?

Comment: Just to clarify, you have created a webservice and were successful in calling it through POSTMAN. Could you tell as to where is IIB engine and POSTMAN residing. Are they both installed on your local machine ?  Next, what do you mean by hit the service from outside POSTMAN ?

Comment: Okay I will try to simplify

Comment: My apologies for not being clear. Okay I will try to simplify:1. I have created a mock server in postman. 2. I tried calling it from my local machine where I have deployed my IIB flow. 3.Here I called my IIB flow, which had a HTTP node, where I have mentioned the mock server url. 4. So I got 'A Web Service request has detected a SOCKET error whilst invoking a web service located at host &1, on port &2, on path &3.' error.

Comment: I would suggest to call the mock web-service hosted in Postman from another tool such as SoapUI and see if you are successfully able to call it. This would result in you getting the exact working url. Then you can configure this URL in the HTTP Request node.

Comment: Or if using Linux curl -vvv "http://someurl" the verbose option will show you what's going on. If possible run it from the same server your IIB node is running on or at least the same subnet.

Comment: I have a windows system. I believe I have to setup SSL in IIB node as the POSTMAN mock server url is of HTTPS protocol by default. What is your suggestion on this. @TJA

Comment: @SatyaPanigrahy you can use Powershell. Have a look at the how to use Invoke-RestMethod https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-curl/